# tooltip is not shown as expected when customized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am working on angularjs google charts. I want to customize the tooltip.
In my tooltip i want to show the multiple series data as well as some text as shown in the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/orQchHKMeErVesXW2M0u?p=preview
I want to see the legend and the title of the value beside the value displayed in the tooltip as shown in the https://plnkr.co/edit/6iw39IRFY7mwdQzjAVR6?p=preview

In the above plunker, i'm not customizing the tooltip and so it works as expected but when i customized the text in tooltip as shown in first plunker link(replaced First Series with Jan - July ...) the tooltip is not shown as expected.
Any advices?

js code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('google-chart-example', ['googlechart']).controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {

  var createChart = function (rows, label) {
        return {
            "type": "ColumnChart",
            "data": {
                "cols": [
                    {"id": label, "label": label, "type": "string"},toolTipVar,
                    {"id": "count", "label": "count", "type": "number"},
                    {"id": "pizza", "label": "Pizza", "type": "number"},
                    {"id": "softdrink", "label": "Softdrink", "type": "number"}
                ],
                "rows": rows
            },
            "options": {
                "title": label,
                "isStacked": "true",
                 focusTarget: 'category',
                // "displayExactValues": true
               "tooltip": {'text' : 'value' }, 
            }
        }
    };

    var toolTipVar = {
        role: "tooltip",
        type: "string",
        p: {
            'html': true
        }
    };

  var data = [
        {"c":[{"v":"First Series"},{"v":"Jan - July" + "\n" + "63" + "\n" + "30" + "\n" + "33"},{"v":63},{"v":"30"},{"v":"33"}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Second series"},{"v":"Aug - Sept" + "\n" + "70" + "\n" + "35" + "\n" + "35"},{"v":70},{"v":"35"},{"v":"35"}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Third series"},{"v":"Oct - Dec" + "\n" + "80" + "\n" + "40" + "\n" + "40"},{"v":80},{"v":"40"},{"v":"40"}]}

    ];
  $scope.myChart = createChart(data, "Data Series");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use a [continuous axis](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous) (`'number'`, `'date'`, `'timeofday'`, etc...) for the first column,

you can provide the tooltip value as the formatted value (`f:`)

```
{"c":[{"v": 0, "f":"Jan - July"},{"v":63},{"v":"30"},{"v":"33"}]},
```

then use `hAxis.ticks` for the axis labels
use the same object notation to set the label value

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: [
    {"v": 0, "f":"First Series"},
    {"v": 1, "f":"Second Series"},
    {"v": 2, "f":"Third Series"}
  ]
},
```

other options are included in the following snippet,
to format the chart similar to using a discrete axis (`'string'`)

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
  packages: ['corechart'],
  callback: drawChart
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
    "cols": [
      {"id": 'title', "label": 'title', "type": "number"},
      {"id": "count", "label": "count", "type": "number"},
      {"id": "pizza", "label": "Pizza", "type": "number"},
      {"id": "softdrink", "label": "Softdrink", "type": "number"}
    ],
    "rows": [
      {"c":[{"v": 0, "f":"Jan - July"},{"v":63},{"v":"30"},{"v":"33"}]},
      {"c":[{"v": 1, "f":"Aug - Sept"},{"v":70},{"v":"35"},{"v":"35"}]},
      {"c":[{"v": 2, "f":"Oct - Dec"},{"v":80},{"v":"40"},{"v":"40"}]}
    ]
  });

  options = {
    title: 'title',
    isStacked: true,
    focusTarget: 'category',
    hAxis: {
      baselineColor: 'transparent',
      gridlines: {
        color: 'transparent'
      },
      slantedText: false,
      ticks: [
        {"v": 0, "f":"First Series"},
        {"v": 1, "f":"Second Series"},
        {"v": 2, "f":"Third Series"}
      ]
    },
    tooltip: {
      text: 'value'
    }
  }

  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

**UPDATE**

placing the above changes in angular...

```
var createChart = function (rows, label) {
      return {
          "type": "ColumnChart",
          "data": {
              "cols": [
                  {"id": label, "label": label, "type": "number"},
                  {"id": "count", "label": "count", "type": "number"},
                  {"id": "pizza", "label": "Pizza", "type": "number"},
                  {"id": "softdrink", "label": "Softdrink", "type": "number"}
              ],
              "rows": rows
          },
          "options": {
            title: 'title',
            isStacked: true,
            focusTarget: 'category',
            hAxis: {
              baselineColor: 'transparent',
              gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
              },
              slantedText: false,
              ticks: [
                {"v": 0, "f":"First Series"},
                {"v": 1, "f":"Second Series"},
                {"v": 2, "f":"Third Series"}
              ]
            },
            tooltip: {
              text: 'value'
            }
          }
      }
  };

var data = [
    {"c":[{"v": 0, "f":"Jan - July"},{"v":63},{"v":"30"},{"v":"33"}]},
    {"c":[{"v": 1, "f":"Aug - Sept"},{"v":70},{"v":"35"},{"v":"35"}]},
    {"c":[{"v": 2, "f":"Oct - Dec"},{"v":80},{"v":"40"},{"v":"40"}]}
  ];
```

Comment: Can i achieve this using   <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>.As in our application we are not using loader.js

Comment: appreciate your help. I see in the above code using DataTable. Please find my demo https://plnkr.co/edit/orQchHKMeErVesXW2M0u?p=preview . This is the way we are implementing in our existing application and cannot introduce new js files or either DataTables as you suggested above.Is the same above behaviour can be achieved in my demo plunker above without using DataTables(using jsapi).

Comment: Please find the updated link https://plnkr.co/edit/XmPWWAEIrHZqls4LhBOa?p=preview.The chart is not as expected.

Comment: remove the tooltip column, isn't needed --> [https://plnkr.co/edit/WBApWlwTIDa7HjOQMyxe?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/WBApWlwTIDa7HjOQMyxe?p=preview) -- changed __UPDATE__ above as well...