# assign the value of ticks: dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

Here is an example of google column chart built using static data : https://plnkr.co/edit/WBApWlwTIDa7HjOQMyxe?p=preview

I want to draw the chart dynamically.One issue i'm facing is how to dynamically assign the value for ticks:[..]
Please find the updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/EGzl2XdQfuMWldzPyfr6?p=preview. 
I tried to assign the values for ticks:[..] later by creating a varibale `dynamicTicks` but it is not working .

PS: Reference [tooltip is not shown as expected when customized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100251/tooltip-is-not-shown-as-expected-when-customized/46100941?noredirect=1#comment79166187_46100941)

--EDITED--

Below is the updated code suggested by @WhiteHat in below thread.
Below is the js code to dynamically get the data and display the chart.Issue is with the below code **the h-axis dynamicTrick is not displayed**, on h-axis it is showing the values given in `f:` property of `{"v": i, "f": hAxisValue}`

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'MyService', function ($scope, $uibModal, MyService) {
    $scope.chart = {};
    $scope.chart.type = "ColumnChart";
    $scope.chart.displayed = false;
    var dynamicTicks = [];
    $scope.chart.options = {
         focusTarget: 'category',
        "fill": 20,
        "displayExactValues": true,
        "isStacked": 'true',
         tooltip: {text: 'value',textStyle: {fontName: '"Arial"'}},
        hAxis: {
            titleTextStyle: {bold: 'true'},
            slantedText: false,
            ticks: dynamicTicks
        },
      };

    $scope.chart.view = {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
    };
     $scope.chart.data = {
        "cols": [
            {id: "label", label: "Label", type: "string"},
            {id: "count", label: "Count", type: "number"},
            {id: "pizza", label: "Pizza", type: "number"},
            {id: "softDrink", label: "SoftDrink", type: "number"},
        ]
    };

    $scope.loadMyChart = function () {
        MyService.getChartData().then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.myResponse= response;
                //check for error
                var count = 0;
                var pizza = 0;
                var softDrink = 0;
                var myRows = [];
                $scope.chart.data.rows = {};
                  var i = 0; var cData=[];
                angular.forEach($scope.myResponse, function (value, key) {
                    count = value.myData.count;
                    pizza = value.myData.pizza;
                    softDrink = value.myData.softDrnk;
                    hAxisValue = value.myData.title;

                   cData = {
                        "c": [{"v": i, "f": hAxisValue}, {"v": passsed},
                            {"v": failed},
                            {"v": notExecute}, {"v": key}]
                    };
                     myRows.push(cData); i++;
           });
                alert("cData.length " + i);
                 for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    alert("in for" + j + "Series" + (j+1)); //This alert is being executed..
                    dynamicTicks.push({
                        v: j, /*cData[j].c[0].v */
                        f: 'Series ' + (j + 1)
                    });
                }
               $scope.chart.data.rows = weekRows;
           },  
    }
         $scope.loadMyChart();    
}]);
```

When used the statement `cData[j].c[0].v`, following error is displayed on browser console and no chart is shown on UI.

```
angular.min.js:sourcemap:119 TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wouldn't you build dynamic ticks where the chart data and options are created?

something like...

```
var createChart = function (rows, label) {
      return {
          "type": "ColumnChart",
          "data": {
              "cols": [
                  {"id": label, "label": label, "type": "number"},
                  {"id": "count", "label": "count", "type": "number"},
                  {"id": "pizza", "label": "Pizza", "type": "number"},
                  {"id": "softdrink", "label": "Softdrink", "type": "number"}
              ],
              "rows": rows
          },
          "options": {
              "title": label,
              "isStacked": "true",
               focusTarget: 'category',
             hAxis: {
            baselineColor: 'transparent',
            gridlines: {
              color: 'transparent'
            },
            slantedText: false,
            "ticks": dynamicTicks,
          },
          tooltip: {
            text: 'value'
          }
          }
      }
  };

var data = [
  {"c":[{"v": 0, "f":"Jan - July"},{"v":63},{"v":"30"},{"v":"33"}]},
  {"c":[{"v": 1, "f":"Aug - Sept"},{"v":70},{"v":"35"},{"v":"35"}]},
  {"c":[{"v": 2, "f":"Oct - Dec"},{"v":80},{"v":"40"},{"v":"40"}]}    
];

var dynamicTicks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  dynamicTicks.push({
    v: data[i].c[0].v,
    f: 'Series ' + (i + 1)
  });
}

$scope.myChart = createChart(data, "Data Series");
```

Comment: [here is a forked plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6ZPLZYKzGmw0tFKnmAl7?p=preview)...

Comment: Thanks for all your support, i have edited and added the dynamic ticks retrieval code in my post above. When executed the code it is not showing any errors and not displaying the ticks on the haxis, instead it is showing the f: property value from {"v": i, "f": hAxisValue} . Any suggestions would be helpful. @WhiteHat

Comment: I'm sorry , Accepted the answer now. I was still trying, unable to get it work in my local application @WhiteHat.