# unable to show ticks on haxis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to show the **ticks values on the haxis**. Below is the code which dynamically get the data and generate a column chart.
Issue is with the below code the h-axis dynamicTicks is not displayed, on h-axis it is showing the values given in f: property of {"v": i, "f": hAxisValue} in cData. The same is working in the demo example https://plnkr.co/edit/G5wUQjVZ0512RvqltIqm?p=preview  but when applied in my local application it is not showing ticks values on haxis. Any suggestions?

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', 'MyService', function ($scope, $uibModal, MyService) {
    $scope.chart = {};
    $scope.chart.type = "ColumnChart";
    $scope.chart.displayed = false;
    var dynamicTicks = [];
    $scope.chart.options = {
         focusTarget: 'category',
        "fill": 20,
        "displayExactValues": true,
        "isStacked": 'true',
         tooltip: {text: 'value',textStyle: {fontName: '"Arial"'}},
        hAxis: {
            titleTextStyle: {bold: 'true'},
            slantedText: false,
            ticks: dynamicTicks
        },
      };

    $scope.chart.view = {
        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
    };
     $scope.chart.data = {
        "cols": [
            {id: "label", label: "Label", type: "string"},
            {id: "count", label: "Count", type: "number"},
            {id: "pizza", label: "Pizza", type: "number"},
            {id: "softDrink", label: "SoftDrink", type: "number"},
        ]
    };

    $scope.loadMyChart = function () {
        MyService.getChartData().then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.myResponse= response;
                //check for error
                var count = 0;
                var pizza = 0;
                var softDrink = 0;
                var myRows = [];
                $scope.chart.data.rows = {};
                  var i = 0; var cData=[];
                angular.forEach($scope.myResponse, function (value, key) {
                    count = value.myData.count;
                    pizza = value.myData.pizza;
                    softDrink = value.myData.softDrnk;
                    hAxisValue = value.myData.title;

                   cData = {
                        "c": [{"v": i, "f": hAxisValue}, {"v": passsed},
                            {"v": failed},
                            {"v": notExecute}, {"v": key}]
                    };
                     myRows.push(cData); i++;
           });
                alert("cData.length " + i);
                //assign the haxis ticks values
                 for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    alert("in for" + j + "Series" + (j+1)); //This alert is being executed..
                    dynamicTicks.push({
                        v: j, /*cData[j].c[0].v - when this is used, it is showing the error angular.min.js:sourcemap:119 TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined and chart is not displayed*/
                        f: 'Series ' + (j + 1)
                    });
                }
               $scope.chart.data.rows = myRows;
           },  
    }
         $scope.loadMyChart();    
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to assign ticks to options, *after* building the ticks...

```
            for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                alert("in for" + j + "Series" + (j+1)); //This alert is being executed..
                dynamicTicks.push({
                    v: j, /*cData[j].c[0].v - when this is used, it is showing the error angular.min.js:sourcemap:119 TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined and chart is not displayed*/
                    f: 'Series ' + (j + 1)
                });
            }
            $scope.chart.options.hAxis.ticks = dynamicTicks;
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, still i could not see the ticks values on haxis.When i have alert for dynamicTicks, it is showing an alert [object Object],[object Object]...@WhiteHat

Comment: I'm sorry , i dont have. I'm getting the values from DB. Almost i have replicated my code in https://plnkr.co/edit/G5wUQjVZ0512RvqltIqm?p=preview but in the static way..When used cData[j].c[0].v in dynamicTicks.push i'm getting exception angular.min.js:sourcemap:119 TypeError: Cannot read property 'c' of undefined so replaced it with value j as shown above..@WhiteHat

Comment: i noticed the code posted in this question above, has the first column as --> `{id: "label", label: "Label", type: "string"}` -- for `ticks` to work, the first column must be of type `'number'`, `'date'`, etc. -- as shown in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46100941/5090771) -- `ticks` will not work with a discrete (`'string'`) axis

Comment: Awesome, thanks it worked :). Appreciate your help.@WhiteHat